# What is this pusher airplane?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I am attempting to identify this aircraft.

The pictures appear to have been taken around 1960.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the only [Bede XBD-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bede_XBD-2), from the early '60s.

According to Wikipedia it was an experimental aircraft with STOL capabilities.

Comment: The tail number must have changed since then, now N327BD is a Piper J3C-65

Comment: @ratchetfreak I guess it would be expected if that number is not in use for a certain number of years, no?

Comment: The aircraft is on static display at Manitowoc airport and still carries the same tail number, as can been seen [here](https://goo.gl/maps/tujugmXX2272)

Comment: Who would have guessed the N...BD stands for Bede. I wonder if he did that with his other planes?

Comment: @jwzumwalt Seems that it is the case for several prototypes, see [photos here](http://www.shu-aero.com/AeroPhotos_Shu_Aero/Aircraft_B/Bede/index.html) of several models